# pdb in JupyterLab not entering interactive mode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pdb

My goal is to run some python scripts with `pdb` or `ipdb` in JupyterLab to capture my debugging history.

I first inserted `set_trace()` in my python script:

```py
import torch
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def train_batch(model_instance, inputs_source, labels_source, inputs_target, optimizer, args):
    inputs = torch.cat((inputs_source, inputs_target), dim=0)
    total_loss, train_stats = model_instance.get_loss(inputs, labels_source)
    total_loss[args.train_loss].backward()

    set_trace() # insert breakpoint

    optimizer.step()
    return train_stats
```

I then run this script in my JupyterLab:

```sh
!python ./trainer/train.py \
    --base_config ./config/sgd_vannila_0.001.yml \
    --dataset Office-Home \
    --class_num 50 \
    --src_address ./data/office-home/Art.txt \
    --tgt_address ./data/office-home/Clipart.txt \
    --name transfer.debug.rand_noise \
    --train_steps 10000 \
    --seed 2 \
    --filter_classes=0,50 \
    --eval_interval 50
```

The execution stops at the breakpoint, but does not provide an interactive box to prompt any `ipdb` instructions. The same is happening for `pdb` or jupyter notebook.

[image]

---

Things I have tried:

- restarting Chrome browser, or my laptop, does not help
- adding breakpoint inside the notebook code block works (please see screenshot below), but I would like to be able to debug code written in my python module file
  [image]

---

Version information:

- ipdb-0.12.2
- Python 3.6.9
- JupyterLab 0.35.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the %run magic command.

```
%run ./trainer/train.py \
--base_config ./config/sgd_vannila_0.001.yml \
--dataset Office-Home \
--class_num 50 \
--src_address ./data/office-home/Art.txt \
--tgt_address ./data/office-home/Clipart.txt \
--name transfer.debug.rand_noise \
--train_steps 10000 \
--seed 2 \
--filter_classes=0,50 \
--eval_interval 50
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the [magic function](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) `%debug` is what you're looking for.  Try inserting the snippet below in a jupyterlab cell and run it:

```
def foo(a,b):
    return(a+b)
c = foo(a=1, b=str(1))
```

This raises a `TypeError`:

[image]

Now, if you insert a cell below, type in `%debug` and run it, you'll get this:

[image]

Now you can run any [ipdb command](http://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2017/07/12/ipdb-cheat-sheet.html), like `h(elp)`:

[image]

Hope this h(elps)!

---

**Edit:**

OP provided the following clarification:

> What I am actually looking for is a proactive way to insert break
> points, i.e., how to insert breakpoint even if there isn't any error.

In that case you an use `from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace` in combination with the ipdb command `bt`. Here's an example:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def foo(a,b):
    return(a+b)
set_trace()
c = foo(a=1, b=1)
```

This triggers the following:

[image]

Now, run the command `bt` and I hope you'll get exactly what you're looking for. I any case, I hope this answers the 'breakpoint without an error' part.
I'm not going to include the entire output of running `bt`, since it's quite a handful. But here's the output from running `?bt` to get some more help on that particular command:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is very nice!
What I am actually looking for is a proactive way to insert break points, i.e., how to insert breakpoint even if there isn't any error.

Comment: @JiangXiang I see! That makes sense. But I don't think it's very clear from the beginning that that's what you're actually after. Would you like to discuss this a bit in a chat session?

Comment: Thanks again! It does not work if I put your code in a `.py` file named `mytest.py`, and run it in jupyter using `!python mytest.py`. It shows `ipdb> ` but there is no input box to enter commands.

Comment: @JiangXiang You've labeled your question `JupyterLab`. My suggestion is therefore directed at a `.ipynb` file and not `.py`. That being said, on my end this approach works just as well in a console as in a notebook.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Maybe there is an issue with my `JupyterLab` installation. Will double check later. Thank you!